# appendChild does not add a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

Here is my code

```
var targetArea = document.getElementById('nav');
var div = document.createElement('div');
var snippet = document.createTextNode('this is a new DIV');
div.appendChild(snippet);
targetArea.appendChild(div);
```

Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dennisboys/BRtYb/6/

developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild, the doc says "Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.", but my example shows, it adds to the top of the list of children. Any idea why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'createTextNode'` Don't you see the error?

Comment: Hi Alvin, how did you get the error? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp, createTextNode is a method listed in doc.

Comment: The error can be seen on the JavaScript console. Also, [better **not** use w3school](http://w3fools.com/). [`document.createTextNode` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode)

Comment: I see no error on jsfiddle. How did you debug my code? I am new to programming and any good debugging tool to recommend? Thanks.

Comment: For almost all browsers, press `F12`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.createTextNode` should be called on `document`.

```
var targetArea = document.getElementById('nav');
var div = document.createElement('div');
var snippet = document.createTextNode('this is a new DIV');
div.appendChild(snippet);
targetArea.appendChild(div);
```

But by your example, you are using jQuery, so why not just do:

```
$('#nav').append('<div>this is a new DIV</div>');
```

***[And the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/BRtYb/8/)***

Comment: Hi xdazz, I just want to test the native DOM method with JS.

Sometimes I am really frustrated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild, the doc says "Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.", but my example shows, it adds to the top of the list of children. I really no idea why.

Comment: Hi xdazz, developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild, the doc says "Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.", but my example shows, it adds to the top of the list of children. Any idea why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: @Dennisboys This is the problem of your html, check the demo again.

Answer (score 1):

createTextNode is a document api, not a element api
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode

I believe you are looking for div.textContent

Comment: +1 *textContent* is not supported by some browsers, though for them *innerText* is a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('nav')
        .appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode('this is a new DIV'));
```

or

```
document.getElementById('nav')
        .appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
        .textContent = 'this is a new DIV';
```

Comment: Hi system(haha, weird to say hello to a system). developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild, the doc says "Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.", but my example shows, it adds to the top of the list of children. Any idea why this happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference between end and top in your opinion? They are not quite related but i think the appearance on screen is depending on the position you're using. For absolute positioning 'end' will mean 'top', for relative will mean right-bottom, or 'end'